# Using button as link that executes javascript prevents OnClick from working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using a button as a link because when the button is pressed it opens a popup of In Line HTML using Javascript (http://www.enthropia.com/labs/ibox/):

```
<a href="#inner_content" rel="ibox&width=800&height=400" title="Search Non Scrum Stories"><asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="Search Stories" OnClick="searchButton_Click" /></a>
```

However, this prevents the OnClick C# from executing when I press the button. How do I fix this?

Comment: It is not valid HTML to put a button inside an `<a>`.  Use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: How can I have the button use this information? href="#inner_content" rel="ibox&width=800&height=400

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this code

```
<a href="#inner_content" rel="ibox&width=800&height=400" title="Search Non Scrum Stories">
</a>

<asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="Search Stories" OnClick="searchButton_Click" />
```

David you must separate html link and button (it's not xaml)

Comment: Now the button no longer creates the popup at all

Comment: publish your code c# it's another problem but the first is corrected

Comment: It's currently empty. I will be using it but haven't yet.     protected void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
    }

Comment: youcan create small popup with window.open, javascipt method

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `LinkButton` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx

Example (from the linked documentation):

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" 
       Text="Click Me" 
       Font-Names="Verdana" 
       Font-Size="14pt" 
       OnClick="LinkButton_Click" 
       runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

separate the tags and put your button in  as a submit button or you can do something like:

```
<form action="ur_popup_page" onsumit="javascriptsunction()">
<asp:Button type="submit" id="searchbutton"/>
</form>
```